# Listbox set Item.Detail at runtime

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am new to Stack overflow and new to Delphi XE7.

I am stuck at a particular part of my programming; I have been working on a Multi Device Application and I formatted a listbox using livebindings designer. The listbox shows the first line of an address (house) which is under Item.text in livebindings and the Postcode to the property is in Item.detail in livebindings. Therefore each entry in the listbox has the first line and the postcode of the address which are taken from an internal database.

When I add a new address to the program I have managed to update the database with the full address and the listbox with the first line of the address at runtime, however I do not know how to access the Item.detail part at runtime to include the postcode. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> "... how to access the Item.detail part at runtime"

See [FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem.ItemData](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem.ItemData).

Access it in runtime via:

```
aPostCodeString := ListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail; // When reading
ListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail := aPostCodeString; // When writing
```

---

When adding an item to the listbox, take a reference to the item at the same time:

```
var
  ListBoxItem : TListboxItem;
...
ListBoxItem := ListBox.Items.Add(someText);
ListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail := aPostCodeString;
```

Comment: Hello and Thank you for the quick reply, unfortunately when I add this to my code it shows up red. Here is code to write my data to the first part of the listbox;                                 while not FDQueryUpdate.Eof do
  begin
    ListBox2.Items.Add(FDQueryUpdate.Fields[0].AsString);
    **bold** ListBox2Item.ItemData.Detail := (FDQueryUpdate.Fields[01].AsString);
  end;  Delphi does not like ListBoxItem Nor does it like ItemData Sorry its all a little muddled I cannot use return in the edit box.

Comment: Please excuse the BOLD word trying to highlight the text I input.

Comment: To address the items in the listbox, use the `Item[index]` syntax. `ListBox2.Item[yourItemIndex].ItemData.Detail :=`.

Comment: Hi, I am really struggling with this. I think the main problem is I am trying to write to another instance of ListBox because everything works but the original ListBox is not being repopulated. I am not too sure what you mean by Item[index] I tried looking up the index in object inspector which was 0 and i tried placing ListBox2[0] where you mentioned but it still came up with faults.

Comment: Hello, I have finally managed to get the listbox populating with the text line and the detail line, however the detail line only shows when I scroll through the list. So on first look at the listBox it looks as though the detail line is missing but once I scroll the lines populate.

Answer (score 2):

Good day, to fill a ListBox from a ClientDataSet can be done with the following procedure

```
procedure TfPpal.setListBox;
var
  ListItem : TListBoxItem;
begin
  ListBox.BeginUpdate;
  cdsDataSet.First;
  while not cdsDataSet.Eof do
  begin
    ListItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox);
    ListItem.Text        := cdsDataSet.FieldByName('id').Text;
    ListItem.ImageIndex  := 1;
    ListItem.Height      := 61;
    ListItem.StyleLookup := 'listboxitemnodetail';
    ListItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aMore;
    LisxBox.AddObject(ListItem);
    cdsDataSet.Next;
  end;
  lbxLisxBox.Height  := 50 + (cdsDataSet.RecNo * 61);
  ListBox.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered my question. First time on Stack Overflow. I am posting the final code which is now working to help anyone who may be looking for a similar result.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  Layout13.Visible := False;
  Layout2.Visible := True;
  MultiView1.Enabled := True;
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  ButtonDelete1.Enabled := True;
  Button2.Enabled := False;
     // setup SQLite in-memory connection
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
with fdqueryInsert do
  begin
    // write new address to database
    Insert;
    fieldbyname('Address1').asstring := edit1.text;
    fieldbyname('Address2').asstring := edit2.text;
    fieldbyname('City').asstring := edit3.text;
    fieldbyname('County').asstring := edit4.text;
    fieldbyname('Postcode').asstring := edit5.text;
    post;
    close;
    open;
  End;
    // draw address line and postcode to listbox
    ListBox2.Clear;
    ListBox2.BeginUpdate;
    FDQueryUpdate.Close;
    FDQueryUpdate.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Address1, Postcode FROM Address';
    try
      FDQueryUpdate.Open;
      Item := TlistBoxItem.Create(ListBox2);
      while not FDQueryUpdate.Eof do
      begin
      // create and format listbox to show bottomdetail
        Item := TlistBoxItem.Create(ListBox2);
        Item.StyleLookup := 'listboxitembottomdetail';
        // draw address to text part and postcode to bottom detail of Listbox item
        Item.Text := (FDQueryUpdate.Fields[0].AsString);
        Item.ItemData.Detail := (FDQueryUpdate.Fields[1].AsString);;
        ListBox2.AddObject( Item );
        FDQueryUpdate.Next;
      end;
    finally
    ListBox2.EndUpdate;
    FDQueryUpdate.Close;
  end;
  // clear editboxes and reset for next address input
  Button7Click(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: looks like a superfluous `Item := TlistBoxItem.Create(ListBox2);` before the while loop?

Comment: If I omit the line when the listbox redraws, only the last entry is shown. When I leave the line in, all entries in the DB are shown in the listbox